# Show that if $A \subseteq B $ then $ A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

for all sets, A, B, C, if $A \subseteq B  $ then $  A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$

So if every element of A is also an element of B then the elements of A $\cdot$ C are identical to the elements of B $\cdot$ C

Suppuse $x\in A$

Then, since $A\subseteq B$ we have $x \in B$.

Hence, $x\in A \cup C $ and $x \in B \cup C$

Therefore, $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$

Comment: **Hint** If $x \in A \cup C$, then $x \in A$ or $x \in C$. What can we say about $x$ with respect to $B \cup C$ then?

Comment: then $x \in B$ or $x \in C$. I'll add my attempt at a proof.

Comment: @SunshineTS Your proof is not quite correct. You must consider $x\in A\cup C$, not $x\in A$. You have proven that $x\in A \implies x\in B\cup C$.

Comment: Hey @SunshineTS! Since you seem to be a 4th year UQ student, probably in Software/Electrical Engineering it might pay to not go posting questions verbatim from your MATH1061 assignment - such as the last 19 questions you have asked, all of which are straight from the assignments. EAIT does not take kindly to this, and I direct you to the [Academic Integrity and Plagiarism policy](http://www.uq.edu.au/myadvisor/academic-integrity-and-plagiarism)

Answer (score 1):

You've only shown that $A \subseteq B \cup C$. The warning sign is your phrase "suppose $x \in A$" - from that point forward, you're only paying attention to members of $A$. But the goal, $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$, says that every member of $A \cup C$ *regardless of whether it is in $A$ or in $C$* is also a member of $B \cup C$.

So you need another case - something that starts with "suppose $x \in C$". If you can show that under that assumption instead you also have $x \in B\cup C$, then you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x\in A\cup C$ then either $x\in A$ or $x\in C$. If $x\in A$ then $x\in B$ as $A\subseteq B$ and thus $x\in B\cup C$. If $x\in C$ then $x\in B\cup C$

Comment: Is my proof not correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is missing a case.

We are given that $x \in A \to x \in B$

We want to show that $x \in A \ \text{or} \ C \to x \in B \ \text{or} \ C$

So there are two cases: $x \in A$, $x \in C$

Case 1: $x \in A$

$x \in A \to x \in B \to x \in B \ \text{or} \ C$

Case 2: $x \in C$

$x \in C \to x \in B \ \text{or} \ C$

Another way is to think of three cases:  $x \in A$ but not $C$, $x \in C$ but not $A$ and $x \in A$ and $C$

Left as an exercise